# How to select a tag in beautifulsoup with an attribute not knowing the value of that attribute?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently scraping data from a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivisions_of_Z%C3%BCrich)  There is a table containing **District , Location , Cost of arms , .... , Non-Swiss Citizens**.

After reading the source page, the table is in second number i.e. another table comes before it.

After extracting this table from the page using code :

```
source = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivisions_of_Z%C3%BCrich").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all("table")
secondTable = tables[1]
```

The only difference between the other **td tag** is an attribute **title** which is present in neighborhood column.

[image: Image showing the above condition]

I need to select only `<td>` tags that have a title attribute but their values are different and I don't know how to select that.

Comment: You should add your expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a selector that just matches the attribute without specifying a value:

```
tables.select("td[title]")
```

or you can use `True` as the value of an attribute with `find_all()` to match any value:

```
tables.find_all("td", title=True)
```